# Spotify native app login on swift opens new instance of my app

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I'm trying to create a streaming app that streams songs from Spotify. User(s) can only stream if he/she as login to their account. To achieve that I created two options

- If a user as Spotify app on their phone open the app to authenticate
  user, when done call my app to allow user stream songs
- If a user doesn't have Spotify app, open safari browser on the phone
  to allow user authenticate, then call my app when done.

**Problem**

Option 2 works perfectly with no issue, allowing user login with the browser and when done call's my app. 
Option 1 instantiate/call Spotify native app from my app to allow user login. When user is done, it calls (Spotify app) another new instance of my app instead of calling the old instance that initiated the Spotify app

**What I've done or tried**

- Check my callback url is correct
- Check my `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is right i.e spotify-action

**Code**

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   //Spotify
   setupSpotify()
}


public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        //Check if this URL was sent from the Spotify app or website
        if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url) {

            //Send out a notification which we can listen for in our sign in view controller
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.Spotify.authURLOpened, object: url)

            return true
        }

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
            app,
            open: url as URL!,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
            annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )
    }

func setupSpotify() {
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = URL(string: SPOTIFY_CALLBACK_URL)
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = "spotifySessionKey"
        //SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenSwapURL = URL(string: SPOTIFY_TOKEN_SWAP_URL)
        //SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenRefreshURL = URL(string: SPOTIFY_TOKEN_REFRESH_URL)

        //For this application we just want to stream music, so we will only request the streaming scope
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]

        // Start the player (this is only needed for applications that's using streaming
        do {
            spotifyPlayer = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
            try spotifyPlayer.start(withClientId: SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't start Spotify SDK")
        }
    }
```

**UIController that calls/initiate Spotify login**

```
func spotify() {
        let appURL = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().spotifyAppAuthenticationURL()!
        let webURL = SPTAuth.defaultInstance().spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()!

        // Before presenting the view controllers we are going to start watching for the notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(receievedUrlFromSpotify(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.Spotify.authURLOpened,
                                               object: nil)

        //Check to see if the user has Spotify installed
        if SPTAuth.supportsApplicationAuthentication() {
            //Open the Spotify app by opening its url
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL)
            }
        } else {
            spotifyAuthWebView = SFSafariViewController(url: webURL)
            //Present a web browser in the app that lets the user sign in to Spotify
            present(spotifyAuthWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func receievedUrlFromSpotify(_ notification: Notification) {
        spinner = AppUtility.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)
        guard let url = notification.object as? URL else { return }

        // Close the web view if it exists
        if spotifyAuthWebView != nil {
            spotifyAuthWebView?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        // Remove the observer from the Notification Center
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: NSNotification.Name.Spotify.authURLOpened,
                                                  object: nil)

        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url) { (error, session) in
            //Check if there is an error because then there won't be a session.
            if let error = error {
                // Pass our error onto another method which will determine how to show it
                self.displayErrorMessage(error: error)
                return
            }

            // Check if there is a session
            if let session = session {

                let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: session)

                //Store spotify session for use later
                self.userDefault.set(sessionData, forKey: MUSIC_STREAM_TOKEN)//"SpotifyAuthSession"
                self.userDefault.synchronize()

                SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().delegate = self
                // If there is use it to login to the audio streaming controller where we can play music.
                SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance().login(withAccessToken: session.accessToken)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sceenshot of two instances of app**

[image: The instance of the app is painted red]

Thanks

Comment: There can only ever be one instance of your app running on a device. Whenever your app is not in the foreground there is the possibility that it will be terminated by iOS due to memory pressure. What does the Xcode debugger say during the login process? Is your app being terminated? Is the Spotify authentication being triggered by the code in `didFinishLaunching`? If so, that would cause an issue because your app is exiting before it has finished launching.

Comment: @Paulw11 Sorry for the late response. I don't understand what you meant by ' Is the Spotify authentication being triggered by the code in didFinishLaunching?' didFinishLaunching will be called when you initiate the app when inside the app (Settings page) you tap a button to log into Spotify. I hope this answers your question. Thanks

Comment: You are calling `setupSpotify` in `didFinishLaunching`. This method is called before your initial view controller is shown.  Until this method returns `true` your app isn't fully running. Causing the Spotify app to launch in `didFinishLaunching` would be bad. You also need to explain what you mean by "another new instance of your app"; there can only ever be one instance of your app running

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 the setupSpotify() method isn't launching Spotify app, its just setting it up. Spotify app gets launched when a button is tap on in Settings ViewController as specified above. What I meant by launching new instance is it opens another ViewController of my app. Please check the image I uploaded above for better clarification